# Add vertical space in tabular cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am attempting to reproduce an existing typeset table.

[image]

The following code produces this table.

I have not been able to correct the second and third cell vertical spacing in the header row.

Thanks in advance for any advice. To include "All wrong, let's start over."

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{3ex}
Ratio of unit lengths \\
$u_x : u_y : u_z$ &
Tan. \phi &
Tan. \theta \\[1ex] \hline
\rule{0pt}{5ex}
$\left\{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        1{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}1{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}1 \\
        \textrm{Isometric}
    \end{tabular}\right\}$ &
$\phi = \theta$ &
= $60^\circ$ \\ [3ex]
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}r}
  2 & 1 & 2 \\
  3 & 1 & 3 \\
  4 & 1 & 4 \\
  5 & 4 & 6 \\
  6 & 5 & 10
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c}
   8 & 1 \\
  18 & 1 \\
  32 & 1 \\
   5 & 1 \\
  11 & 1
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c}
   8 &  7 \\
  18 & 17 \\
  32 & 31 \\
   3 &  1 \\
   5 &  8
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do that with `makecell`. I added some simplification to the code (`\hspace{1em}` is simply `\quad`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{3ex}
\makecell{Ratio of unit lengths\bigstrut[t] \\
$u_x : u_y : u_z$} &
Tan. $ \phi $ &
Tan. $ \theta $ \\[1ex] \hline
\rule{0pt}{5ex}
$\left\{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        1{\quad:\quad}1{\quad:\quad}1 \\
        \textrm{Isometric}
    \end{tabular}\right\}$ &
$\phi = \theta$ &
= $60^\circ$ \\ [3ex]
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}r}
  2 & 1 & 2 \\
  3 & 1 & 3 \\
  4 & 1 & 4 \\
  5 & 4 & 6 \\
  6 & 5 & 10
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c}
   8 & 1 \\
  18 & 1 \\
  32 & 1 \\
   5 & 1 \\
  11 & 1
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c}
   8 & 7 \\
  18 & 17 \\
  32 & 31 \\
   3 & 1 \\
   5 & 8
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it: treat the second row in the first header entry as a second row.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    \hline
    \rule{0pt}{3ex}
    Ratio of unit lengths &     % first row
    Tan. \phi &
    Tan. \theta \\
    $u_x : u_y : u_z$ & & \\    % second row
    [1ex] \hline
    \rule{0pt}{5ex}
$\left\{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        1{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}1{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}1 \\
        \textrm{Isometric}
    \end{tabular}\right\}$ &
$\phi = \theta$ &
= $60^\circ$ \\ [3ex]
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}r}
  2 & 1 & 2 \\
  3 & 1 & 3 \\
  4 & 1 & 4 \\
  5 & 4 & 6 \\
  6 & 5 & 10
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c}
   8 & 1 \\
  18 & 1 \\
  32 & 1 \\
   5 & 1 \\
  11 & 1
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{1em}:\hspace{1em}}c}
   8 &  7 \\
  18 & 17 \\
  32 & 31 \\
   3 &  1 \\
   5 &  8
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

To center the 2nd and 3rd header also vertically you might need a different table package. There is a way to do it with tabular using m{width}, but it works like p{width} i.e. aligns left, while you wanted center c.